How can I inspect queue size of an USB CDC device from macOS?
I'm experiencing communication problems between a device and software running on MacOS. Both are connected over USB CDC. Communication is stuck and I suspect a bug in either part.
I would love to see, if there is any data stored in the device driver, that would be ready to be collected by an application, but is not collected.
Is there any system tool, that provides the information about queue sizes?

Have you exhausted the OS logging in console app? Errors should be logged there and it’s way less work than making a USB test app in Xcode to probe this device programmatically.

Well, I assume, that either my firmware on the device is not working correctly or the test app on the mac. I thought, there must be some way to see, if there is data in the device driver, that is not picked up by the test application.
